# How exactly does matter cause spacetime curvature? Is it the result of another force?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, mass-energy

In general relativity matter is said to curve spacetime. But I am still not sure how to physically visualize it. Is it an expansion or contraction? Is space being pulled in or is it being pushed out? And since it is the bending of spacetime and not just space, does it mean space is continuously being pulled in/pushed out? And in either case, is another force needed to explain why matter curves spacetime?

Comment: Have you completed a course GR?

Comment: not yet, but I have learnt about it from posts, articles and videos

Comment: @Neelim, then you have not learned about it, and this post will not help you learn either. I would suggest working with a good textbook, e.g. Misner-Thorne-Wheeler

Comment: Feynman was once asked how a magnet works in terms of the concepts and forces used in everyday life. He replied with, (quoting him from memory!) "you should be asking me to explain how the everyday-life forces work with electromagnetism, not the other way around". Source of quote: recently published Coleman's lectures called "QM in your face". Similarly with gravity: it just works the way GR says it does. If you're looking for an explanation why that is so, there simply isn't one. Perhaps one day GR will be explained by a more fundamental theory, but everything we have now is less fundamental

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will read up on it. I am aware that all the concepts and nuances cannot be grasped without a textbook and the mathematics. But I was hoping for a qualitative, summarised answers to the questions I asked

Comment: @Prof. Legolasov haha, I agree with Feynman’s line of thinking. The way I see it is that it maybe possible to have more fundamental theory than GR, or maybe another theory is needed in combination with GR to explain everything. It also maybe that GR itself needs to be modified. Perhaps the reason we haven’t found them yet is because GR is so well established that most people are trying to fit in with GR, instead of digging deeper and questioning assumptions

Comment: I think illustrations like [this](https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fstartswithabang%2Ffiles%2F2018%2F08%2Fspacetimelu31.jpg) do a pretty good job visualizing the curvature of space. (It should be spacetime, but I don't think that's possible)

Comment: From this diagram it seems like space is being pulled in, creating a stretching effect. Seems like expansion at the surface and outward edges and contraction towards the centre. Does that match with the equations? And also if the time component were added, would it mean that the lines were moving inwards continuously?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Here's a video of Feynman expressing that viewpoint (those not as succinctly as your quote): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO0r930Sn_8&t=7m18s (after the intro, he returns at about 4m15s, with a punchline at 7m18s) "Richard Feynman Magnets"

Answer (score 3):

In my earlier answer I addressed the questions about visualization.

However, in this case the title of your question is different from the content of your question.

So the type of your question is "How *exactly* does [...]"

I'm going with the following assumption about your expectation: since physics has explained so many things successfully you have an expectation that physics theories always give *exhaustive explanation*.

What I can say about physics is this: at the *periphery*, at the bleeding edge, physicists are in a 'choose your battles' situation.

Example from history of physics:
Newton's law of universal gravity. In Newton's time there was no prospect of providing an explanation of how gravity could possibly operate over the vast distances of the solar system. In fact, some contemporaries objected to Newton's concept of gravity on that very ground. Newton argued: the merit of this law of gravity is that it *unifies*: it describes both the orbits of planets and the gravity on Earth. The physics community accepted the law of universal gravity on that merit.

This is what I mean with 'choose your battles'. If the community of scholars would have insisted "No, we want an explanation first, without explanation we reject this concept of gravity." then they would have bogged themselves down completely.

If you grant that there is such a thing as spacetime, and you grant that curvature of spacetime can act as the mediator of gravitational interaction, then you are in a position to formulate GR.

You have to grant several more things, among them the principle of equivalence.

Conversely, if you don't grant those things then you deprive yourself of the means to formulate GR.

Physicists are willing to accept theories on the basis of their *merit*. Physicists do not insist on exhaustive explanation. They would very much like exhaustive explanation, but they don't let that desire get in the way of progress.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do agree with what you said. The merit of a theory is based on how accurately and precisely it describes and predicts reality. The way I think about is that there can be a finite set of physical theories, all of which we don’t know yet, which can be combined to describe and predict an infinite number of phenomenon with 100% accuracy. However if there are an infinite number of laws, then it will never be exhaustive. But that would imply that there will always be a higher level of theories that can get closer and closer to 100% accuracy, but still never reach it

Comment: History has shown that big changes in paradigms can be needed to solve seemingly small inaccuracies. As you said, Newton first created such a shift, and it worked very well within a domain. Then Einstein expanded the domain and while the results seem to be modified slightly, the shift in paradigm seems to be quite big, which is ofcourse what I am studying now. But since it still does not accurately describe things like cosmic inflation, black holes, and requires dark matter and dark energy, implies that there can be new paradigms that explain things better, even if its not exhaustive

Comment: That is why I try to question existing paradigms and think of new ones, which may not match with the conventional line of thinking. But it also doesn’t mean that I don’t appreciate and value the merit of existing theories

Comment: @Neelim comments are not for discussion. They are for improving the question or answer.

Comment: Got it, I’ll stop

Comment: The "abstract", and the "conclusion" or "discussion" sections of physics papers (in paragraphs at their beginning and end) usually boil the equations down to plain English (or whatever language they're written in).

Answer (score 2):

For a visualization I suggest [the river model of gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060)

The authors of that paper: professor [Andrew Hamilton](https://www.colorado.edu/physics/andrew-hamilton) and Jason Lisle.

The authors of the paper emphasize that the river model is a visualization model, *not* a physical model.

The river model is mathematically self-consistent. That means that you can be confident that it will allow you to visualize the physics in an overal coherent way.

For instance: in terms of the river model there is only a single form of time dilation. By contrast: most visualizations are in terms of a separate velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation.

The distinction between velocity time dilation and gravitational time dilation is very common, but it is at odds with GR. In terms of the equations of GR there is only a single form of time dilation.

Comment: I've upvoted this interesting answer, but would like to point out that a somewhat similar model of Kerr-Newman BH's, currently visible freely in a 2010 paper at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222531808_Nonsingular_Dirac_particles_in_spacetime_with_torsion , utilizes the more recent Einstein-Cartan-Sciama-Kibble theory in a departure from the river model's conventional idealization of particles as point-like (so as to avoid both shear and the need for any singularity), and successfully predicts the LHC's inability to produce micro-BH's.